# Hide lightline for MiniBufExplorer

Tags: vim, statusline

Is there any way to do not show status line (I am using [lightline](https://github.com/itchyny/lightline.vim)) for some windows - MiniBufExplorer or NERDTree ?

[image: Status line for MiniBufExplorer]

Answer (score 2):

You can locally clear the `'statusline'` setting (am empty value will bring up the default, but you can choose just the background color group to make it effectively disappear):

```
:setlocal statusline=%#Normal#
```

To apply that automatically to MiniBufExpl windows, you can use an `:autocmd`, either based on the characteristic buffer name (`BufWinEnter` event), or if the plugin sets a `'filetype'`, on the `FileType` event.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is the best thing we can do about it. Thank you!